# @Transactional with 1 save statement

Tags: spring, grails, transactional

Does it make sense mark with spring's @Transactional a method with a single save sentence? 
For example:

```
// does it make sense mark it with @Transactional if it only has 1 save sentence?
@Transactional
public void saveMethod() {
    user.save()
}
```

Comment: Don't you need Transactional to be able to run any updates? Otherwise the connection is read-only, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you´re using Spring data interface, you dont need use @transactional annotation. Only in case that you want to provide two execution against the database and you want to share the transaction, so then rollback of both actions can be made.

Anyway it is always better use @transactional even as read-only for get queries(setting the FlushMode to MANUAL to let persistence providers potentially skip dirty checks when closing the EntityManager), so I would suggest put the @transactional as Service layer and read-only for get queries.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you recommend putting @Transactional annotation in methods with only save/update sentence ?

Comment: No, I suggest put in class level, and for select queries use @Transactional(ReadOnly="true")

Answer (score 1):

Yes because any "modifications" on the database requires a transaction (to commit the changes). You might think otherwise because of `auto-commit`, but in the end, there is still a transaction there somewhere.

But it is always a good thing to explicitly define the boundaries of your transaction (when transaction is started and when it is committed).